# Adding truststore certificate to Apache Kafka without bouncing Kafka cluster

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, truststore, apache-kafka-security

We are using Apache kafka_2.11-1.1.0. Whenever we want to add a new Kafka producer or consumer, we update the new certificate in truststore. Once the cert is added, we have to restart the kafka cluster. Is there a way to add cert without Rolling restart of Kafka ?
Technically the truststore update shouldn't require Kafka to restart.

Comment: I too had same question, the official documentation tells about rolling updates...one broker at a time, but that leads to too much of rebalancing on a heavily loaded cluster. Any alternatives?